# Method to model exponential fit line coefficients based on main function parameters

Tags: fitting, exponential-smoothing, function

I have a quite complicated trigonometric equation I was able massage into a parametric function that takes four parameters as inputs/arguments, say: $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$. Regardless of the combination of the parameters, the function is always periodic so I'm able to calculate the local maxima, $x^+$, and minima $x^-$. Both maxima and minima can be fit quite nicely using an exponential fit line in the general form $y(x)=pe^{-rx}$ and $y(x)=-qe^{-rx}$, respectively.

Due to the complexity of the analytical form of my function I am unable to figure out the analytical form of parameters $p$, $q$, and $r$. I'm wondering if there is a suitable ML or other method/procedure to get a parametric form of $p$, $q$, and $r$ with respect to $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$. That is, to obtain $p=p(a,b,c,d)$, $q=q(a,b,c,d)$, and $r=r(a,b,c,d)$. I assume I'd need to suggest a general form of these three functions and I'm fine with that. I am not asking for a solution, code, etc. just the pointers to what I should research further. I'll do my own homework.

Obviously, I can easily vary parameters $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ to obtain as large data sets of $p$, $q$, and $r$ as needed.

Thanks.